# Why constructor doesn't execute all the code using WinAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, constructor

This is my class constructor:

```
ActionButton::ActionButton(CallbackFunction function, void* param, HWND parent, int x, int y, int heigth, int width) :
    m_function(function), m_parameters(param), m_window(NULL)
{
    HWND m_window = CreateWindowEx(0, L"Action button", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 
        x, y, width, heigth, parent, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    SetWindowLongPtr(m_window, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)this);
    ShowWindow(m_window, SW_NORMAL);
}
```

I used debuger and found that it executes `CreateWindowEx()` but after pressing F11 program jumped off the constructor (and I'm using only one thread). Is something wrong with my code?

---

After `CreateWindowEx` there is executing window procedure with parameters e.g `WM_CREATE`, so step after `CreateWindowEx` is not in constructor, after executing a few window procedure callbacks it goes back into constructor.

Comment: Are you debugging a release build? If you have optimizations turned on it can mess with the debugger. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: It jumps in your window procedure for some create messages ( WM_NCCREATE, WM_NCCALCSIZE, and WM_CREATE to be exact)

Comment: Set a break point on GetLastError, see if you can hit it.

Comment: Are you going to delete this question too after I spend 15 minutes writing an answer for it?
Your other question had problems with your WndProc setup, so you are probably just trashing your stack.

Comment: Did you check, if an exception is thrown in `CreateWindowEx()`? Then of course this will abort the contructor's routine.

Comment: @sebi The Windows API exposes a C interface. There are no C++ exceptions. SEH exceptions usually do not pass API boundaries either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While executing [`CreateWindow[Ex]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) the system calls the window procedure associated with the window class for several messages ([`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632626.aspx), [`WM_NCCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632635.aspx), [`WM_NCCALCSIZE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634.aspx), [`WM_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx)) before it returns. While the window procedure handles these messages the `GWLP_USERDATA` is not yet set. The system however guarantees, that `GWLP_USERDATA` is zero-initialized so you can safely query and handle the uninitialized `GWLP_USERDATA`.

If you want to set `GWLP_USERDATA` before `CreateWindow[Ex]` returns you will have to set up a CBT hook hook using [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) and handle the [`HCBT_CREATEWND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx) event. This lets you store any data attached to a `HWND` before the window procedure gets called with a `WM_NCCREATE` message.

Unrelated to your question, `GWLP_USERDATA` is fairly unreliable. A lot of applications will store their own data there, overwriting each other's data. Since this seems to be a private window class that you control you should allocate space in the [Extra Window Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx#extra_window_memory) instead and store your data there.

Comment: @Ben There is no `CREATESTRUCT` passed to `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` which is sent prior to `WM_NCCREATE` for top-level windows. Hooking `CreateWindow` is the only way to pass this information to the first message sent to a window's message proc. You are right, other applications **shouldn't** store data in your `GWLP_USERDATA`. That doesn't keep them from doing it anyway. If you control the window class you will wind up with less headaches by allocating a pointer sized entry into the extra window memory. You are free to disagree and implement your solutions based on good faith instead.

Comment: @Ben Assume that you're writing a framework where the WndProc is a class member and you must ensure that this WndProc gets **all** messages you have to hook `CreateWindow`. That's what MFC does for this and a few other reasons. I agree that it is rude to hijack another window's private data. But that doesn't imply that it's not happening. And since `GWLP_USERDATA` is guaranteed to exist for any window that's where 'enhancement' software tends to store its data. I mentioned the extra window memory as a safer alternative that has zero additional cost (in terms of runtime or lines-of-code).

Comment: @Ben I don't follow your line of thought: Just because it is illegal to run around shooting people, it doesn't happen? That is basically what you keep repeating. It doesn't work that way in the Real World™, I'm afraid. As for *"calling [the] substitute instead"*: What substitute? You surely don't have a substitute for `CreateWindow`. And you certainly don't know what the first message to a window is, in Windows vNext. You are free to post your very own answer, detailing your superior approach. I'm anxious to see what a `CREATEPARAMS` is.

Comment: "You surely don't have a substitute for `CreateWindow`."?  What exactly does "hook the CreateWindow[Ex] API" mean to you?  (Sorry, I've been typing `CREATEPARAMS` but I mean `CREATESTRUCT`)

Comment: I'm starting to think you're intending to recommend something entirely sensible.  And that your only mistake is using the word "hook", when you don't mean "overwrite the first few bytes of the function with a jump to a replacement version" and/or "adjust a function pointer to point to the address of a replacement version", which is what [it means to hook a library function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking).  Once you fix your question to describe what you actually recommend doing, all the confusion should go away.

Comment: @Ben I'm using the term *Hooking* to mean what [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) describes. Hooking `CreateWindowEx` (using a CBT hook) allows you to get a go at a fully initialized `HWND` structure prior to `CreateWindowEx` calling back to a window's WndProc for the first time. Regardless of what the first message is you already set up your own custom WndProc, unhook the window, and don't worry about it any more. If you are inclined read the *wincore.cpp* code (part of MFC) which does exactly that.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes much more sense.  However you should describe that as "hooking (or handling) `HCBT_CREATEWND`", not "hooking the `CreateWindowEx` API", since you're installing a CBT hook/callback and not hooking a function.  But note that (according to the docs) [`HCBT_CREATEWND` is called before Windows sends `WM_NCCREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx)... back to the same problem with messages sent before `WM_NCCREATE`.

Comment: The CBT handler sounds like trouble as well, since it'll be called for a window created by any thread in the system, not just yours... right?

Comment: @Ben `SetWindowsHookEx` has a `dwThreadId` parameter that lets you specify a filter for a single thread.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a reasonable solution.  I still don't understand why the function that looks up a object pointer from HWND can't be smart enough to create the connection on the first message, using thread-local storage, but it seems either way would work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36490/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-ben-voigt)